# Flutter: App crashes while trying to display interactive maps using map_view on android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to display an interactive map when user clicks on an address using `map_view` plugin. The problem that i have is every time i click on the address, the app crashes.

This is my project structure / configuration (in details):

**lib\main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:map_view/map_view.dart';

import './pages/product.dart';

void main() {
  MapView.setApiKey(<my_google_developer_api_key>);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**lib\pages\product.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:map_view/map_view.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showMap() {
    final List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[
      Marker('position', 'Position', product.location.latitude,
          product.location.longitude)
    ];
    final cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
        Location(product.location.latitude, product.location.longitude), 14.0);
    final mapView = MapView();
    mapView.show(
        MapOptions(
            initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
            mapViewType: MapViewType.normal,
            title: 'Product Location'),
        toolbarActions: [
          ToolbarAction('Close', 1),
        ]);
    mapView.onToolbarAction.listen((int id) {
      if (id == 1) {
        mapView.dismiss();
      }
    });
    mapView.onMapReady.listen((_) {
      mapView.setMarkers(markers);
    });
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  rxdart: ^0.22.1+1
  map_view: ^0.0.14
  location: ^1.4.1
```

**android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.50'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.easy_list">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="easy_list"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value=<my-google-developer-api-key>/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value=<my-google-developer-api-key>/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**error messages displayed in the console**

```
I/flutter ( 5555): {showUserLocation: false, showMyLocationButton: false, showCompassButton:
false, hideToolbar: false, cameraPosition: {latitude: 21.0277644, longitude: 105.8341598, tim
e: 0, altitude: 0.0, speed: 0.0, bearing: 0.0, horizontalAccuracy: 0.0, verticalAccuracy: 0.0
, zoom: 14.0, tilt: 0.0}, title: Product Location, mapViewType: normal}
W/art     ( 5555): Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.
support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffCo
lorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have i
ncorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/zzbz    ( 5555): Making Creator dynamically
I/art     ( 5555): Enter while loop.
I/DynamiteModule( 5555): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and
remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
I/DynamiteModule( 5555): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, ver
sion >= 221
W/System  ( 5555): ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
W/System  ( 5555): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gm
s/app_chimera/m/00000071/n/armeabi-v7a
W/System  ( 5555): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gm
s/app_chimera/m/00000071/n/armeabi
I/Google Maps Android API( 5555): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API( 5555): Google Play services package version: 18382017
D/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Process: com.example.easy_list, PID: 5555
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{c
om.example.easy_list/com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityT
hread.java:2724)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityTh
read.java:2789)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.
java:1527)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:92
4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: B
inary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: E
rror inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be speci
fied once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android
.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.r.b(:com.google.andro
id.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):23)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.a(:com.google.andr
oid.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):10)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.f.a(:com.google.andr
oid.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.go
ogle.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFra
gmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-26026400
2):25)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j.a(:com.google.andro
id.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):73)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at hs.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamit
e@18382046@18.3.82 (040306-260264002):4)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadEx
ception(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zzc(Unknown Sourc
e)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzc(Unk
nown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.createD
elegate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zza
(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onI
nflate(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(U
nknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:13
02)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(Fr
agmentManager.java:3714)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(Fra
gmentController.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsO
nCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateV
iew(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(Fragm
entActivity.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflat
er.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflat
er.java:727)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:49
5)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:42
6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:37
7)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentV
iew(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(Ap
pCompatActivity.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivi
ty.kt:31)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumen
tation.java:1118)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityT
hread.java:2677)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityTh
read.java:2789)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.
java:1527)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:92
4)
Lost connection to device.
```

I expect the interactive map to display on the screen but instead, the app crashes. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should include the error logs, to help us understands what goes wrong...

Comment: do you know where i can find the error log? the app literally crashes on my android phone with no information of where the error is logged into

Comment: @HayiNukman I get some errors in the console, do you want to me to post that?

Comment: yes, that it.. the error logs displayed on the console, you should post it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem on your cases is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5555): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The API key can only be speci
fied once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android
.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

try to delete this line:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value=<my-google-developer-api-key>/>
```

and run it again....

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give you 50 upvotes if i could. I'm so happy for this :)